# Ng-repeat list with the number of times many values of an element are repeated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make a table which shows the name of the person, the number of times his name is repeated in the array, and the number of times each of the "colors" are also repeated of that certain name.

This is the array for the table:

```
var firstArray = [{
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Green": "Yes",
  "Pink": "Yes",
  "Yellow": "No"
},
{
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Green": "Yes",
  "Pink": "No",
  "Yellow": "No"
},
{
  "Name": "Mary",
  "Green": "No",
  "Pink": "No",
  "Yellow": "No"
},
{
  "Name": "Mary",
  "Green": "No",
  "Pink": "Yes",
  "Yellow": "No"
},
{
  "Name": "Mike",
  "Green": "Yes",
  "Pink": "Yes",
  "Yellow": "Yes"
},
{
  "Name": "Mike",
  "Green": "No",
  "Pink": "No",
  "Yellow": "No"
},
{
  "Name": "Mary",
  "Green": "Yes",
  "Pink": "Yes",
  "Yellow": "Yes"
}
]
```

And this is how I need to display the table:
[image]

I don't know the names that people will introduce. They can introduce the same name as many times they want or a completely different one.

I added this code to count the number of times each name is repeated:

```
var namesArray = [];
firstArray.forEach(function(e) {
    namesArray.push(e.Name);
});

var countNames = namesArray.reduce(function(obj, b) {
    obj[b] = ++obj[b] || 1;
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(countNames);
```

But after this step I'm completely blank on how to make the table, also don't know how to sum all the green, pink and yellows for each Name.
Does somebody has a better approach? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your colors are constant, here is basic example:

```js
angular
    .module('colors', [])
    .controller('colorsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        let firstArray = [{
            "Name": "John Doe",
            "Green": "Yes",
            "Pink": "Yes",
            "Yellow": "No"
        }, {
            "Name": "John Doe",
            "Green": "Yes",
            "Pink": "No",
            "Yellow": "No"
        }, {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Green": "No",
            "Pink": "No",
            "Yellow": "No"
        }, {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Green": "No",
            "Pink": "Yes",
            "Yellow": "No"
        }, {
            "Name": "Mike",
            "Green": "Yes",
            "Pink": "Yes",
            "Yellow": "Yes"
        }, {
            "Name": "Mike",
            "Green": "No",
            "Pink": "No",
            "Yellow": "No"
        }, {
            "Name": "Mary",
            "Green": "Yes",
            "Pink": "Yes",
            "Yellow": "Yes"
        }];
    
        $scope.colors = {};
    
        firstArray.forEach(function(item, index) {    
            if ($scope.colors[item.Name]) {
               $scope.colors[item.Name].Total += 1;
                $scope.colors[item.Name].Green += (item.Green === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0);
                $scope.colors[item.Name].Pink += (item.Pink === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0);
                $scope.colors[item.Name].Yellow += (item.Yellow === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0);
            } else {
                $scope.colors[item.Name] = {
                    'Total': 1,
                    'Green': (item.Green === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0),
                    'Pink': (item.Pink === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0),
                    'Yellow': (item.Yellow === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0)
                };
            }
        });
}]);
```

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
}

.table th,
.table td {
    padding: 0.75rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="colors" ng-controller="colorsCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Green</th>
                <th>Pink</th>
                <th>Yellow</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in colors">
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.Total }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.Green }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.Pink }}</td>
                <td>{{ value.Yellow }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableArray = [];
firstArray.forEach(function(e) {

 var o = tableArray.find(obj => {
  return obj.Name === e.Name;
 });
 if(o  === "undefined") { o =  new Object(); }
 else{ 
  //delete object from array before adding it again
  tableArray.splice(tableArray.findIndex(item => item.Name === e.Name), 1);
 }

 o.Name = e.Name;
 o['Total'] = o.Total? ++o['Total'] : 1;
 //set default values for colors
 o['Green'] = o.Green? o.Green : 1;
 o['Pink'] = o.Pink? o.Pink: 1;
 o['Yellow'] = o.Yellow? o.Yellow: 1;

 //if there is an addition add it 
 o['Green'] = (e.Green=="Yes")? ++o['Green'] : o['Green'];
 o['Pink'] = (e.Pink=="Yes")? ++o['Pink'] : o['Pink'];
 o['Yellow'] = (e.Yellow=="Yes")? ++o['Yellow'] : o['Yellow'];
 tableArray.push(o);
});
```

Comment: This gives me an error on line `o.Name = e.Name;`, it says **Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined**

Comment: Also have another question: how would you translate the expression: `item => item.Name === e.Name` without arrow functions (=>), because IE doesn't support them and I'm not sure how to translate this one exactly